# Transforming a ray to NDC coordinates

Tags: c++, glm, raytracing

I am trying to have ray tracing with a mesh using NanoRT and I want to be able to allow for a model transform on top of my view and projection transforms.

I have successfully transformed my ray from object space to NDC by computing the inverse of the view and projection matrices, but I am having some trouble to do the same when having a model transform as well. This is what I have tried:

```
glm::vec4 NDCPos      = glm::vec4((2.0f * float(mousePositionX)) / widthHeight.x - 1.0f, 
                        1.0f - (2.0f * float(mousePositionY)) / widthHeight.y, 
                        1.0f,
                        1.0f);
glm::mat4 inverseModel = glm::inverse(model);
glm::vec4 viewCoords   = glm::inverse(projection) * NDCPos;
viewCoords             = glm::inverse(view) * viewCoords;
glm::vec4 worldCoords  = inverseModel * glm::vec4(viewCoords.x, viewCoords.y, -1.0f, 0.0f);

glm::vec3 rayDir = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(worldCoords));
glm::vec3 rayOri = inverseModel * glm::vec4(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z, 0.0f);

nanort::Ray<float> ray;
ray.org[0] = rayOri.x;
ray.org[1] = rayOri.y;
ray.org[2] = rayOri.z;

ray.dir[0] = rayDir.x;
ray.dir[1] = rayDir.y;
ray.dir[2] = rayDir.z;

float kFar = 1.0e+30f;
ray.min_t = 0.0f;
ray.max_t = kFar;

nanort::TriangleIntersector<> triangle_intersector(glm::value_ptr(modelDataVertices[0]), &indexes[0], sizeof(float) * 3);
nanort::TriangleIntersection<> isect;
bool hit = accel.Traverse(ray, triangle_intersector, &isect);
if (hit)
{
    hitPos = rayOri + rayDir * isect.t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was not having a 1.0f in the w component:

```
glm::vec3 rayOri = glm::vec3(inverseModel * glm::vec4(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z, 1.0f));
```